# Image not displaying in image tag in angulajs and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am on learning angularjs so pardon me if you observe any weakness. I have been on this problem for hours so I decided to drop it in here. I am following an online tutorial to display images from the camera and gallery so i ended with this codes divided into different sections. After taking picture from gallery or from my camera nothing happens on my display view.
This is the code in my services.js

```
angular.module('starter')

.factory('FileService', function(){
    var images;
    var IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY = 'images';

    function getImages(){
        var img = window.localStorage.getItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY);
        if(img){
            images = JSON.parse(img);
        }
        else {
            images = [];
        }

        return images;
    };

    function addImage(img){
        images.push(img);
        window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
    };

    return {
        storeImage: addImage,
        images: getImages
    };

})

.factory('ImageService', function($cordovaCamera, FileService, $q, $cordovaFile){

    function makeid(){
        var text = '';
        var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor (Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text;
    };

    function optionsForType (type){
        var source;

        switch (type){
            case 0:
                source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
                break;
            case 1:
                source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
                break;
        }

        return {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
    }

    function saveMedia(type) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var options = optionsForType(type);


        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
            var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = makeid() + name;
            $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
              .then(function(info) {
                FileService.storeImage(newName);
                resolve();
              }, function(e) {
                reject();
              });
            });
        })
    }


    return {
        handleMediaDialog: saveMedia
    }

});
```

This is my code in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding" ng-controller="ImageController">
    <button class="button button-full button-energized" ng-click="addMedia()">
      Add image
    </button>
    <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="sendEmail()">
      Send mail
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <ion-scroll direction="x" style="height:200px; min-height: 200px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
      <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}" style="height:200px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;"/>
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>
</body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code in my controllers.js file

```
    angular.module('starter')

    .controller ('ImageController', function ($scope, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaFile, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaEmailComposer, $ionicActionSheet, ImageService, FileService ){

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
            $scope.images = FileService.images();
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        $scope.urlForImage = function(imageName){
            var trueOrigin = cordova.file.dataDirectory + imageName;
        return trueOrigin;
        }

        $scope.addMedia = function(){
            $scope.hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
                buttons:[
                    {text: 'Take photo'},
                    {text: 'Photo from library'}
                ],
                titleText: 'Add Images',
                cancelText: 'Cancel',
                buttonClicked: function(index){
                    $scope.addImage(index);
                }
            });
        }


      $scope.addImage = function(type) {
        $scope.hideSheet();
        ImageService.handleMediaDialog(type).then(function() {
          $scope.$apply();
        });
      }


        $scope.sendEmail = function() {
        if ($scope.images != null && $scope.images.length > 0) {
          var mailImages = [];
          var savedImages = $scope.images;
          if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform() == 'Android') {
            // Currently only working for one image..
            var imageUrl = $scope.urlForImage(savedImages[0]);
            var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, name)
            .then(function(info) {
              mailImages.push('' + cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + name);
              $scope.openMailComposer(mailImages);
            }, function(e) {
              reject();
            });
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < savedImages.length; i++) {
              mailImages.push('' + $scope.urlForImage(savedImages[i]));
            }
            $scope.openMailComposer(mailImages);
          }
        }
      }

      $scope.openMailComposer = function(attachments) {
        var bodyText = '<html><h2>My Images</h2></html>';
        var email = {
            to: 'some@email.com',
            attachments: attachments,
            subject: 'Devdactic Images',
            body: bodyText,
            isHtml: true
          };

        $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
            var name = attachments[i].substr(attachments[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, name);
          }
        });
      }
    });

This is the code in my services.js file

angular.module('starter')

.factory('FileService', function(){
    var images;
    var IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY = 'images';

    function getImages(){
        var img = window.localStorage.getItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY);
        if(img){
            images = JSON.parse(img);
        }
        else {
            images = [];
        }

        return images;
    };

    function addImage(img){
        images.push(img);
        window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
    };

    return {
        storeImage: addImage,
        images: getImages
    };

})

.factory('ImageService', function($cordovaCamera, FileService, $q, $cordovaFile){

    function makeid(){
        var text = '';
        var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor (Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text;
    };

    function optionsForType (type){
        var source;

        switch (type){
            case 0:
                source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
                break;
            case 1:
                source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
                break;
        }

        return {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
    }

    function saveMedia(type) {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var options = optionsForType(type);


        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
            var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = makeid() + name;
            $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
              .then(function(info) {
                FileService.storeImage(newName);
                resolve();
              }, function(e) {
                reject();
              });
            });
        })
    }


    return {
        handleMediaDialog: saveMedia
    }

});
```

This is the code in my app.js file

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
//    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
//      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
//    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Assuming all the necessary plugins have been imported via the command prompt. Please help me out.

Comment: I will suggest you to simply read plugin documentation and instead of following some tutorial just use plugin functions by your own. Documentation is very well explained with "how to use" code part.